# Understanding javascript promises; stacks and chaining

Tags: javascript, promise, chain

I've been running into a couple of problems with javascript promises, particularly with stacked chains.

Can anyone explain to me the difference (if there is any!) between these different implementations?

IMPLEMENTATION 1

```
var serverSidePromiseChain;
serverSidePromiseChain = async().then(function(response) {
    console.log('1', response);
    return response;
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log('2', response);
    return true;
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log('3', response); // response expected to be 'true'
    return async3();
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log('4', response);
    return async4();
})
```

IMPLEMENTATION 2

```
var serverSidePromiseChain;
serverSidePromiseChain = async().then(function(response) {
    console.log('1', response);
    return response;
});

serverSidePromiseChain.then(function(response) {
    console.log('2', response);
    return true;
})
serverSidePromiseChain.then(function(response) {
    console.log('3', response); // response expected to be 'true'
    return async3();
})
serverSidePromiseChain.then(function(response) {
    console.log('4', response);
    return async4();
})
```

IMPLEMENTATION 3

```
var serverSidePromiseChain;
serverSidePromiseChain = async().then(function(response) {
    console.log('1', response);
    return response;
});

serverSidePromiseChain = serverSidePromiseChain.then(function(response) {
    console.log('2', response);
    return true;
})
serverSidePromiseChain = serverSidePromiseChain.then(function(response) {
    console.log('3', response); // response expected to be 'true'
    return async3();
})
serverSidePromiseChain = serverSidePromiseChain.then(function(response) {
    console.log('4', response);
    return async4();
})
```

Does the fact that part of the chain returns a value ('true' in step 2) change the behavior? Do promises require all returned values to be async promises to keep behavior?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are illustrating the different between chaining and branching.  Chaining wil sequence multiple async operations so one starts when the prior one finishes and you can chain an arbitrary number of items to sequence one after the other.

Branching hooks up multiple async operations to all be in flight at the same time when one trigger operation completes.

Implementations 1 and 3 are the same.  They are chained.  Implementation 3 just uses a temporary variable to chain, whereas implementation 1 just uses the return value from `.then()` directly.  No difference in execution.  These `.then()` handlers will be called in serial fashion.

Implementation 2 is different.  It is branched, not chained.  Because all subsequent `.then()` handlers are attached to the exact same `serverSidePromiseChain` promise, they all wait only for the first promise to be resolved and then all subsequent async operations are all in flight at the same time (not serially as in the other two options).

---

It may be helpful in understand this to dive one level down into how this works with promises.

When you do (scenarios 1 and 3):

```
p.then(...).then(...)
```

What happens is as follows:

1. The interpreter takes your `p` variable, finds the `.then()` method on it and calls it.
2. The `.then()` method just stores the callback it was passed and then returns a new promise object.  It does not call its callback at this time.  This new promise object is tied to both the original promise object and to the callback that it stored.  It will not resolve until both are satisfied.
3. Then the second `.then()` handler on that newly returned promise is called.  Again, the `.then()` handler on that promise just stores the `.then()` callbacks and they are not yet executed.
4. Then sometime in the future, the original promise `p` gets resolved by its own async operation.  When it gets resolved, it then calls any `resolve` handlers that it stores.  One of those handlers will be the callback to the first `.then()` handler in the above chain.  If that callback runs to completion and returns either nothing or a static value (e.g. doesn't return a promise itself), then it will resolve the promise that it created to return after `.then()` was first called.  When that promise is resolved, it will then call the resolve handlers installed by the second `.then()` handler above and so on.

When you do this (scenario 2):

```
p.then();
p.then();
```

The one promise `p` here has stored resolve handlers from both the `.then()` calls.  When that original promise `p` is resolved, it will call both of the `.then()` handlers.  If the `.then()` handlers themselves contain async code and return promises, these two async operations will be in flight at the same time (parallel-like behavior), not in sequence as in scenario 1 and 3.

Comment: "Implementation 2 is different. It is branched, not chained. Because all subsequent .then() handlers are attached to the exact same serverSidePromiseChain promise, they all wait only for the first promise to be resolved" is (for me) the most concise and clear answer. Very well said. Thanks!

Comment: You say "Branching hooks up multiple operations to all run in **parallel** when the same operation completes."  This is misleading in that it can be read as saying that the *handlers* get run in parallel, which isn't true (the handlers get run in the same thread, in serial, in the same order in which the corresponding `then`s were called).  Similarly, last sentence "these two .then() handlers will run in parallel" is even more clearly misstated: no, the .then() handlers don't run in parallel, but the async work they schedule may.

Comment: @DonHatch - I've tweaked the wording some, but you're quibbling a bit here.  The concept here is that branching allows the async operations to all be in flight at the same time (often referred to as "in parallel") while chaining forces strict serial operation so the 2nd async operation is not even started until the first one has resolved.  Yes, JS is single threaded so no JS code actually ever runs in parallel in any circumstance, but the async operations themselves are in-flight at the same time which is parallel-like behavior for the async operations rather than serial behavior.

Comment: Thanks.  I do think it's an important distinction, and not necessarily obvious, especially to people (such as myself) who are using your answer as material to learn about, and solidify my understanding of, how javascript and promises work.  Thanks for humoring me.  The wording looks very good to me now.

Answer (score 3):

Implementation #1 and #3 are equivalent. Implementation #2 differs, as there's no chain there, and all callbacks will be executed on the same promise.

Now let's discuss a little bit about promise chains. The [specs](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-39) tell that:

> 2.2.7 `then` must return a promise
>   2.2.7.1 If either `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` returns a value `x`, run the Promise Resolution Procedure `[[Resolve]](promise2, x)`
>   2.3.3 If `x` is a promise, adopt its state

Basically calling `then` on a promise returns another `promise`, which gets resolved/rejected based on the `callback return value`. In your case you are returning scalar values, which are then propagated down the chain to the next promise.

In your particular case, here's what happens:

- #1: you have 7 promises (`async` call plus 4 `then`'s, plus two from `async3()`/`async4`), `serverSidePromiseChain` will point to the last promise returned by `then`. Now if the promise returned by `async()` is never resolved/rejected, then `serverSidePromiseChain` will also be in the same situation. Same with `async3()`/`async4()` if that promise is also not resolved/rejected
- #2: `then` is called multiple times on the same promise, additional promises are created however they don't affect the flow of the application. Once the promise returned by `async()` will be resolved, all the callbacks will be executed, what the callbacks return will be discarded
- #3: this is equivalent to #1 only now you explicitly pass along the created promises. When the promise returned `async()` gets resolved, the first callback will be executed, which resolves the next promise with `true`, the second callback will to the same, the third one will have the chance to convert the chain to a failed one, if `async3()`'s promise gets rejected, same with the callback that returns `async4()`'s promise.

Promise chains are best suitable for actual async operations where the operations depend on the results of the previous one, and you don't want to write a lot of glue code, and you also don't want to reach to [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com).

I wrote a series of articles on my blog about promises, one describing the chaining feature of promises can be found [here](http://blog.cristik.com/2015/03/promises-advanced/); the article is targeted for ObjectiveC, however the principles are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation 1 and 3 appear to be equivalent.

In implementation 2, the last 3 `.then()` functions all act on the same promise.  The `.then()` method returns a new promise.  A fulfilled promise's value cannot be changed. See [Promises/A+ 2.1.2.2](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-16).  Your comment in implementation 2, that response is expected to be true, indicates that you expect otherwise.  No, `response` will not be true (unless that was the value from the original promise).

Let's just try it out.  Run the following code snippet to see the differences:

```js
function async(){ return Promise.resolve("async"); }
function async3(){ return Promise.resolve("async3"); }
function async4(){ return Promise.resolve("async4"); }


function implementation1() {
  logContainer = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
  console.log("Implementation 1");
  var serverSidePromiseChain;
  serverSidePromiseChain = async().then(function(response) {
    console.log('1', response);
    return response;
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log('2', response);
    return true;
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log('3', response); // response expected to be 'true'
    return async3();
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log('4', response);
    return async4();
  });
}

function implementation2() {
  logContainer = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
  console.log("Implementation 2");
  var serverSidePromiseChain;
  serverSidePromiseChain = async().then(function(response) {
    console.log('1', response);
    return response;
  });
  serverSidePromiseChain.then(function(response) {
    console.log('2', response);
    return true;
  });
  serverSidePromiseChain.then(function(response) {
    console.log('3', response); // response expected to be 'true'
    return async3();
  });
  serverSidePromiseChain.then(function(response) {
    console.log('4', response);
    return async4();
  });
}

function implementation3() {
  logContainer = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
  console.log("Implementation 3");
  var serverSidePromiseChain;
  serverSidePromiseChain = async().then(function(response) {
    console.log('1', response);
    return response;
  });
  serverSidePromiseChain = serverSidePromiseChain.then(function(response) {
    console.log('2', response);
    return true;
  });
  serverSidePromiseChain = serverSidePromiseChain.then(function(response) {
    console.log('3', response); // response expected to be 'true'
    return async3();
  });
  serverSidePromiseChain = serverSidePromiseChain.then(function(response) {
    console.log('4', response);
    return async4();
  });
}

var logContainer;
var console = {
  log: function() {
    logContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("div")).textContent = [].join.call(arguments, ", ");
  }
};

onload = function(){
  implementation1();
  setTimeout(implementation2, 10);
  setTimeout(implementation3, 20);
}
```

```css
body > div {
  float: left;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```