# Can a chain be stopped without sending an error message to the console?

Tags: javascript, promise, chain

With the following code, when I reject the promise, I see the first console.log but I also see the second console.log. This is expected since the rejection only affects the next "then()".

The question is, is there any operator equivalent to a "break" in a loop, so that you can jump off the chain? The fast answer would be yes, with a non-catched reject() or throw(), but both approaches will send an error message to the console (will they stop the whole code execution?)

**So the question is, can it be done "cleanly"?**

*My first assumption was that by catching the reject/error this would do the trick, but it is not the case

```
Promise.resolve()
.then(function(){
  do stuff
  return Promise.resolve();
})
.then(function(){
  if (a === 'this')
    return Promise.resolve();
  else
    // is there any "break" equivalent here?
    return Promise.reject();
})
.then(function(){
  console.log('seen if not rejected');
},function(){
  console.log('seen if rejected');
})
.then(function(){
  console.log('seen all the time');
});
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: a is not defined(…)`

Comment: @CoryDanielson That isn't the problem. They're asking why returning a rejected promise does not end the chain.

Comment: @CoryDanielson please see that as pseudo-code

Comment: because youre continuing to call `.then()`. [from mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) **The then() method returns a Promise.**  *It takes two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.* Your final `.then()` should be in with `stuff` rather than chained again.

Comment: It's because you `catch` the rejection in the function where you log `console.log('rejected, end of chain');`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan really this post is specific of AngularJS, which can be confusing for non-angular people (or even for beginners like me)

Comment: $q and Promise use essentially the same semantics. If you'd prefer, there are plenty of other duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16371129/215552, http://stackoverflow.com/q/29853578/215552, etc.

Comment: For a solution, [just](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24663315/1048572) put the `console.log('only executed if not rejected');` right inside the callback with the `stuff`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, I have edited the question to be more precise in the question, which is now not why it doesn't stop, but how it can be stopped without sending messages to the console

Comment: @Bergi is the one with the dupehammer, not me :). Are the answers on the marked duplicate not clear as to how to do this? As an aside, you shouldn't be changing the question if you already have answers to the previous one. That's a "bait and switch" that's frowned upon.

Comment: For the new question, it's probably a duplicate of [How to properly break out of a promise chain?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29499582/1048572) (also see the questions linked from there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `.then(success, error)` callbacks return promises.

That is:

```js
Promise.reject()

.then(function () {
  // won't be called, as above promise is rejected
}, function () {
  // will be called, and returns a resolved promise by default;
  // if you want the next error callback to be called,
  // you need to return a rejected promise or to throw an error
})

.then(function () {
  // 1: called if above .then returns a resolved promise
}, function () {
  // 2: called if above .then returns a rejected promise or throws an error
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As you pass a second argument (`onRejected` function) to `then` method, the rejection is actually caught. And it returns a promise too, so you can continue chaining.

If you remove the `onRejected` function in your third `then`, you will see an uncaught exception in console, for example:

```
Promise.reject()
  .then(function(){
    console.log('resolved');
  })
  .then(function(){
    console.log('you cannot see me');
  })

// Uncaught (in promise)
```

And yes, you can `catch` the exception, if it's not caught by `onRejected`:

```
Promise.reject()
  .then(function(){
    console.log('resolved');
  })
  .catch(function(){
    console.log('you can see me');
  })

// you can see me


Promise.reject()
  .then(function(){
    console.log('resolved');
  }, function(){
    console.log('rejected');
  })
  .catch(function(){
    console.log('you cannot see me');
  })

// rejected
```

Regarding my experiences, in real business scenario we usually want to separate irrelevant logic. So we would caught the rejection in `onRejected`, do something, then throw the exception to `catch` method (either in itself or in chaining `then`):

```
Promise.reject()
  .then(function(){
    console.log('resolved');
  }, function(e){
    console.log('rejected');
    throw e
  })
  .catch(function(){
    console.log('you can see me');
  })

// rejected
// you can see me
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because you catch the rejection. The two block below are equivalent:

**example1**

```
var stuff = function () {

};
var doStuff = function () {

};
var a = 'notThis';

Promise.resolve()
    .then(function () {
        doStuff();
        return Promise.resolve();
    })
    .then(function () {
        if (a === 'this')
            return Promise.resolve();
        else
            return Promise.reject();
    })
    .then(function () {
        stuff();
    }, function () {
        console.log('rejected, end of chain');
    })
    .then(function () {
        console.log('only executed if not rejected');
    });
```

**example2**

```
var stuff = function () {

};
var doStuff = function () {

};
var a = 'notThis';

Promise.resolve()
    .then(function () {
        doStuff();
        return Promise.resolve();
    })
    .then(function () {
        if (a === 'this')
            return Promise.resolve();
        else
            return Promise.reject();
    })
    .then(function () {
        stuff();
    })
    .catch(function () {
        console.log('rejected, end of chain');
    })
    .then(function () {
        console.log('only executed if not rejected');
    });
```

Comment: [No, they're not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572).

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but could you pls explain why not?

Comment: It's explained in the linked answer. If you don't understand something, please aske there.