# Is there a difference between promise.then.then vs promise.then; promise.then

Tags: angularjs, promise

I want to know is there a difference between following two?

1. `aPromiseObj.then(fn1).then(fn2).catch(fn3);`
2. `aPromiseObj.then(fn1); aPromiseObj.then(fn2); aPromiseObj.catch(fn3);`

Will the work flow changed?

ps: I am in angular environment, though I would like to think this in a broader term.

Comment: Yes. The first method chains the promises while the second executes the `fn1`, `fn2` resolution handlers and `fn3` rejection handler on the same promise (`aPromise`).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have asked about **"chaining"** vs. **"branching"**.

Assuming that `f1` and `f2` represent asynchronous operations that return promises, yes there is a significant difference.  For option 1:

1. It serializes `fn1` and `fn2` so that `fn2` is not called until after the promise returned by `fn1` has been resolved.
2. `.catch()` applies to an error in either `fn1` or `fn2` or if `aPromiseObj` rejects.
3. `fn2` will not be called if `fn1` rejects.

For option 2:

1. `fn2` does not wait for `fn1` to resolve.  `fn2` is called as soon as `fn1` returns similar to `fn1();  fn2();`.  This means the async operations started by `fn1` and `fn2` will both be in-flight at the same time (sometimes referred to running in parallel instead of running serially).
2. The `.catch()` does not apply to either because it is not on the promise that is created by either of the `.then()` calls.  The `.catch()` in option 2, only applies to if `aPromiseObj` rejects, not `f1()` or `f2()`.
3. Both `fn1` and `fn2` will be called regardless of an error in either.

Another related question/answer: [Understanding javascript promises; stacks and chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853578/understanding-javascript-promises-stacks-and-chaining/29854205#29854205)

Comment: You say "For option 2: 1. It runs `fn1` and `fn2` in parallel, not in series".  This is wrong; it executes `fn1` and `fn2` in series in both cases.  The difference in control flow in absence of errors, as I understand it, is that in option 1, *if* fn1 returns a promise, fn2 won't run until that promise is fulfilled, and in that case fn2 will be passed the fulfilled value of the promise returned by fn1 (rather than the fulfilled value of aPromiseObj).

Comment: @DonHatch - I clarified the wording.

Comment: Thanks, it looks right to me now.

Comment: I'd just add that in option 2, the `.catch()` block would be triggered if `aPromiseObj` throws. Also, the `then()` blocks would not trigger since `aPromiseObj` was not successful.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta - Thx, I updated the answer to include that point.

Comment: Good answer, just ran into an issue / bug like this recently while fixing an angularjs app (the promise was branching and not chained), was not something I expected (or have tried to do) when you come from an angular 2+ background. Thanks