# Javascript return Promise from function - promise chain vs variable

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js

Is there a difference between these two ways for returning promise from a function

```
var promise;
promise = callAsync();
promise.then(doSomething).then(doSomethingElse);
return promise;
```

vs

```
var promise;
promise = callAsync();
return promise.then(doSomething).then(doSomethingElse);
```

I thought both approaches are same, but in a mocha test case, only second approach is working.

Comment: only the second approach is correct, the first returns the callAsync promise only

Comment: @JaromandaX would't the promise initiated by callAsync() would have created the promise chain in both cases ?

Comment: if that were so, then I'd be wrong. But I'm not wrong :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are certainly not the same.  Each `.then()` returns a new promise.  So,

```
return promise;
```

is returning the original promise, but:

```
return promise.then(doSomething).then(doSomethingElse);
```

is returning a new promise that is the result of calling both `.then()` methods.  The difference is that the latter one is returning a promise that is influenced by the functions called in those `.then()` methods, whereas the first promise is only influence by `callAsync()` and has nothing to do with the other `.then()` handlers.

The first promise is only monitoring `callAsync()`.  It has absolutely nothing to do with what happens in other `.then()` handlers.  The key to understanding `.then()` is that it returns a new promise and it is that new promise that is influenced by what happens in the `.then()` handlers.

For more info, read this answer: [Is there a difference between promise.then.then vs promise.then; promise.then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216619/is-there-a-difference-between-promise-then-then-vs-promise-then-promise-then/32216660#32216660) to understand the difference between chaining and branching.