# jQuery $.when does not wait for deferred chain to complete ajax calls

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

Here i try to load several JS files sequentially. Problem is `$.when` does not wait for the chain to complete. But the last `$.Deferred.then` works as expected. What should i do to make `$.when` work?

```js
var urls = [
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js",
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/photoswipe/4.1.2/photoswipe.js",
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/photoswipe/4.1.2/photoswipe-ui-default.js"
];
var xxx = $.Deferred();
xxx.then(function() {
        options = {
            dataType: "script",
            url: urls[0],
            cache: false
        };
        return $.ajax(options).promise();
    })
    .then(function() {
        options = {
            dataType: "script",
            url: urls[1],
            cache: false
        };
        return $.ajax(options).promise();
    })
    .then(function() {
        options = {
            dataType: "script",
            url: urls[2],
            cache: false
        };
        return $.ajax(options).promise();
    }).then(function() {
        $("body").append("This is correct. All files are loaded.<br>");
    });

$.when(xxx).done(function() {
    $("body").append("This is wrong. JS files are not loaded yet.<br>");
});
xxx.resolve();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/ergec/fmrj6qgp/

Comment: If it is working with `$.Deferred.then` as expected then why you want to use `$.when` ?

Comment: There is no reason to use `$.when()` here at all or your `$.Deferred()`.  Start the chain with `$.ajax(...).then()`.  Your last `.then()` handler should work just fine to know when the whole chain is done.  There's also no reason to use `return $.ajax().promise()` when return `$.ajax(...)` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method does not work because you create two branches off the same promise.  You have the equivalent of:

```
var xxx = $.Deferred();
xxx.then(...).then(...);     // promise chain 1
xxx.then(...)                // promise chain 2
xxx.resolve();               // start the race between the two promise chains
```

That is simply a race between two separate promise chains that are not sequenced or coordinated.  Whichever one takes less time to execute will get to its end first.  There is zero coordination between them.

See [Chaining vs. Branching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853578/understanding-javascript-promises-stacks-and-chaining/29854205#29854205) and [p.then().then() vs. p.then(); p.then()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216619/is-there-a-difference-between-promise-then-then-vs-promise-then-promise-then/32216660#32216660) for further explanation.

And, your use of `$.when(xxx).done()` is unnecessary and not really part of the issue at all.  You would get the same result with `xxx.done()`.

---

You can fix it by only using one promise chain:

```
p.then(...).then(...).then(...)
```

Then, everything is properly sequenced and coordinated.

```
var urls = [
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js",
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/photoswipe/4.1.2/photoswipe.js",
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/photoswipe/4.1.2/photoswipe-ui-default.js"
];
let options = {
  dataType: "script",
  url: urls[0],
  cache: false
};
$.ajax(options).then(function() {
    let options = {
      dataType: "script",
      url: urls[1],
      cache: false
    };
    return $.ajax(options);
}).then(function() {
    let options = {
      dataType: "script",
      url: urls[2],
      cache: false
    };
    return $.ajax(options).then(function() {
          $("body").append("Last script loaded<br>");
    });
}).then(function() {
      $("body").append("This is correct. All files are loaded.<br>");
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tLp68a3q/

---

Or, if you still wanted to initialize your chain with `var xxx = $.Deferred()` so you could start it later with `xxx.resolve()`, then you can do that too, but you can't use `xxx.then()` or `$.when(xxx)` because that is a completely separate branch that is not linked to the other promise chain at all.

Working example starting with `$.Deferred()`: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/y5n3hb99/