# Object not defined when using then promise for chained promises in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I'm using the following code to use chained promise for `invoice` object in Sequelize. But `invoice` object is undefined for the second usage of `then`.

```
Invoice.create({
    //set values for invoice object
}).then(invoice => { //update company id
    //invoice belongs to a company
    Company.findOne({where: {id: companyId}}).then(company => {
        return invoice.setCompany(company)
    })
}).then(invoice => {
    console.log('Invoice is: ' + invoice)
    //create child items
    invoice.createItem({
        //set item values
    })
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Invoice create error: ' + err)
})
```

The output in the console is `Invoice is :undefined`. What I have done wrongly here?

Comment: Are you trying to chain the promise response or branch it out? Have a look at this response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216619/is-there-a-difference-between-promise-then-then-vs-promise-then-promise-then/32216660#32216660

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you need to return the promise in your first `.then` callback.

Change this:

```
Invoice.create({
    //set values for invoice object
}).then(invoice => { //update company id
    //invoice belongs to a company
    Company.findOne({where: {id: companyId}}).then(company => {
        return invoice.setCompany(company)
    })
}).then(...)
```

To:

```
Invoice.create({
    //set values for invoice object
}).then(invoice => { 
    // return this promise
    return Company.findOne({where: {id: companyId}}).then(company => {
        invoice.setCompany(company)
        // you also need to return your invoice object here
        return invoice
    })
}).then(...)
```